# What is the max length of mp3 file?

Tags: mp3, media, mpeg

I was wondering if mp3 file has a sound length limit.

If there is some limit, I would like to know what it is.

Comment: To the upvoter, is this question not off topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko It's grey area, but I don't believe it to be off-topic.  When choosing a file format to output from your software, understanding the limits of various formats is important.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no limit.  There is nothing in a pure MPEG stream indicating length, which is what I would imagine where the limit would come into play.  MPEG frames are lined up one after the other, with nothing linking them (except for the bit reservoir, if used).

Certain container formats may have other limits, but if you're talking about a plain MP3 file I think you are only limited by the file system and practical limits built into the software you're using to record and playback the file with.

For what it's worth, I've made MP3 files that are several weeks in length without any difficulty.

Comment: @brad can you share your technique?  I can only get to about 7 hours in ffmpeg no matter what file format I use.

Comment: @garrettlynch My lengthy MP3s were usually rips from internet radio.  I've never found an inherent limit in FFmpeg either... I often use FFmpeg to encode internet radio streams.  Can you post a new question on SuperUser.com with your full FFmpeg command, the start of its STDERR output, and the end of its STDERR output when it fails, and then drop a link to that question here?

Comment: @brad right so low bit rate and sample rate.  It seems the issue I had was a corrupt file to begin with.  I'm now encoding 34 hours which is what I need.  The main issue I have been running into is not audio length but file size.  As soon as I hit about 3.5gb+ there are issues - perhaps this 2/4gb issue I see referred to on a lot of forums.

Comment: @garrettlynch You might have a filesystem issue unrelated to the files.  Post a new question on SuperUser.come with your exact output.